# this is null in the inside method, how is this even possible?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a class Star that inherits from Object. It has a GameObject field.
Here is code:

```
public class Star : Object {
    public GameObject starObject;
    // code omitted
}
```

It has a method that I use for selection.

```
public void selectStar () {

    Debug.Log ("Inside star selection");

    mapManager.selectionStarDidChange(this);

    selected = true;
}
```

I have another script from which I call that method, it detects input.

```
public class StarObjectHandler : MonoBehaviour {

    public Star starScript;

        void OnMouseOver() 
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
            Debug.Log ("Mouse registered star selection");
            starScript.selectStar();
        }
    }
}
```

But when I call the first method, somehow `this` becomes `null`. How can I even call methods on `null` and they work?

What is wrong here? I checked the `starScript` in second class, it is not `null`.

In the log I get "Mouse registered.." and then "Inside star selection" as expected.

EDIT1:

Here is the method that is getting invoked from this:

```
public void selectionStarDidChange(Star newlySelected)
{
if (newlySelected) {

    starSelector.transform.position = newlySelected.position;

} else {

    starSelector.transform.position = new Vector2(-10, -10);
}

if (lastSelectedStar) {
    lastSelectedStar.deselectStar();
}

if (lastSelectedShip) {
    lastSelectedShip.deselectShip();
}

lastSelectedStar = newlySelected;
}
```

It always goes the else route, and logging here says that newlySelected is null.

EDIT2:

Here is the project if anyone feels interested to see what is wrong:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/napsqknlw3hjuku/Orion2.zip?dl=0

EDIT3:

I managed to localize the error to this code:

```
Star star = new Star();
Debug.Log ("Is star null? __" + (star == null) + "__");
```

Somehow this returns true, I will have to look up object instantiation.

Comment: How exactly have you observed `this` being `null`? It's quite hard to tell what's going on just from snippets - if you could provide a short but complete example, it would be easier to help you. It *is* possible to end up in an instance method with `this` equal to null in C#, but it usually requires some interesting delegate creation.

Comment: @JonSkeet When debugging, also the method that is getting invoked on mapManager goes to the branch where parameter is null.

Comment: It may be an unexpected Mono behavior because any call of method is just simple as a call a method by static address with "this" as a first argument. It seems that the Mono which is used in Unity can allow you to call a method for a null object in some cases.

Comment: @ViacheslavSmityukh added project code

Comment: How does selectionStarDidChange() compile? Doesn't the compiler reject the implicit conversions from Star to bool in the if clauses?

Comment: There are still just *snippets* of code. Again, a *complete* example would be far easier to help you with.

Comment: @mikeagg I changed that to != null, doesn't matter, same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the problem was that this code returned null instead of an object. I have no idea how the rest of the program worked with this being null, and I can't understand why it returns null.

It is a subclass of Object class. I changed it to no superclass and it worked.

```
Star star = new Star();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes looks like you have declared variable without assigning it

```
Star star = new Star();
```

Will solve the issue